# Are affinoid algebras over nontrivially valued fields Jacobson?

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, rigid-analytic-geometry

It is well-known that for any field $k$ with valuation the Tate algebra $k\{T_1,\dots,T_n\}$ is Jacobson (see Bosch-Güntzer-Remmert for nontrivial valuations; for trivial valuations those are just polynomial rings), and hence so are all strictly $k$-affinoid algebras.

> Are all $k$-affinoid algebras over nontrivially valued fields Jacobson?

I know this fails for $k$ with trivial valuation, since then $k\{r^{-1}T\}=k[[T]]$ for $r>1$, which is a reduced local ring but not a field, but I was unable to find any information about what happens when we take generalized Tate algebras but discard trivially valued fields.

I expect the answer to be negative (if for no other reason that I haven't been able to find any mention of the positive answer in the literature!), but I was not able to find a counterexample. I know that $k\{r_1^{-1}T_1,\dots,r_n^{-1}T_n\}$ themselves have vanishing Jacobson radical, and the classical example $k\{r^{-1}T,rT^{-1}\},r\not\in\sqrt{|k^*|}$ of a non-strictly $k$-affinoid algebra is not a counterexample, since it's a field.